# Build agent not able to see NuGet package on Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, tfsbuild

I'm using the Visual Studio Team Service online Ci/CD process to automate our build.  This has been working until we have a project that utilizes .NET core and the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptograhpy package in our project.  We also upgraded the IDE to VS 2017.

Below is the error on the build agent:

[image]

Things that I've tried:

1. I've verified I have the NuGet Restore step in my build definition prior to building my project and in its log I see that it downloads this package.

> 2018-06-29T13:51:48.4627803Z Checking compatibility for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 2.0.3 with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 (win-x86).
>   2018-06-29T13:51:48.4628026Z All packages and projects are compatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 (win-x86).
>   2018-06-29T13:51:48.4628199Z Committing restore...

2. I verified that my build machine has this package installed.

[image]

3. I can build my project without any error via my local Visual Studio 2017 on this machine where my build agent runs as a service.
4. My agent runs as a service using the account that has administrator right.
5. I updated our .NET Core runtime to 2.1.
6. We are using the default setting that comes with the NuGet, pls note this has working up until recently.

[image]

Can anyone give me a hint on this? could this be some sort of environment parameter or permission issue or something else at play?

I also look at the project file .csproj of the solution that caused this error or the solution that needs this package and here is its definition:

[image]

Comment: Hard to say, did you check the history changes for the csproj?

Comment: Hi Miguel, this project is a new .csproj that has just been added to our solution.  It requires VS 2017 because it use the .NET Core 2.0, but if I compile my solution locally using Visual Studio 2017 on the same machine where the build agent runs then it compiles.

Comment: Do you have the latest Visual Studio Build Tools also installed in that machine? The TFS service should use the Build Tools directly, not the VS2017.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15#

Comment: Yup, I don't know if it is the same version but when I was googling around for answer, that is one of the recommendation and the version of Build Tool I have is 15.7.22703.2026

Comment: Can you enable a verbose flag for the TFS Build step? Something in the logs may suggest you what is happening.

Comment: Hi Miguel, see my answer below, I'm puzzled of the step to fix as well.  I'll look more into it later but thanks for trying to help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet to see why I did below fix the issue but I post it anyway;  If I find the real reason then I'll update my answer.

I manage to get this to compile after I went into my Build definition at the Build Visual Studio task and go into the Advanced -> MSBuild Architecture and changed it from MSBuild x86 to MSBuild x64.

[image]

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could mark your solution as an answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)